# SSL with Blue eyes

Tags: scala, rest, ssl, https, frameworks

I am considering using the Blue eyes framework in order to build HTTPS RESTful webservices in Scala for a project. However, as the documentation is pretty poor, I can't figure out if we can configure it in order to work with SSL or not?

Many thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Blueeyes is unmaintained; I would not recommend it for a new project. I'm a big fan of Spray myself, but if you want something that's very similar to Blueeyes you might like to use Redeyes.